# linear algebra dimension exercise

Tags: linear-algebra

Problem statement

Let $V$ be a $K-$vector space of finite dimension $n$, and let $\{v_1,..., v_k\} \subset V$ a linearly independent set. Prove that if $W$ is a subspace of $V$ of dimension strictly greater than $n-k$, then there is $w \in W$ not null such that $w \in <v_1,..., v_k>$.

Though it may be obvious, I am not so sure how to prove this. Suppose there is $W$ that contradicts the statement, How could I arrive to an absurd from here? Is there a direct way to show this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $W=<x_1,x_2, \ldots,x_k>$ and $S=<w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_{n-(k-1)}>.$ It is enought  to prove that $\dim(S\cap W )>0$. We have 
$$
\dim( S\cup W) =\dim S + \dim W -\dim S\cap W=n-(k-1)+k-\dim S\cap W=\\
=n+1- \dim S\cap W.
$$
But $\dim( S\cup W) \leq n,$ thus $n+1- \dim S\cap W \leq n$ and $\dim S\cap W \geq 1$   as required.

Answer (score 1):

Take the projection $\pi : V \to V/W$, and restrict to the subspace $V' := \langle v_1,...,v_k \rangle$. Since $\dim V' = k$ and $\dim V/W = \dim V - \dim W < k$, by rank-nullity, $\ker \pi \big|_{V'} \neq 0$, i.e. some nonzero element $v' \in \langle v_1,...,v_k \rangle$ is in $W$.